# How to get "scalar" value from pandas Dataframe based on columns values conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

here is the form of my pandas df:

```
id year CW value
c1 2020 45 5543.3
c2 2020 45 4434 
c3 2020 45 3343.4
c4 2020 45 2399.62
c5 2020 45 1233.34
c1 2020 44 5432
c5 2020 44 4423
c4 2020 44 3342.34
c3 2020 44 2322.3
c2 2020 44 1677.5
...
...
...
c2 2019 2 5222.3
c1 2019 2 4444 
c4 2019 2 3333
c3 2019 2 2222.62
c5 2019 2 1111.34
c5 2019 1 5959
c3 2019 1 4949
c1 2019 1 3939.34
c4 2019 1 2929.3
c2 2019 1 1919.5
```

The data frame is sorted by "year", "CW", "value" descending.

I want to compare the newest week performance of c1, c2, c3, c4 and c5 in terms of value per CW (calendar week) over the previous week of the actual year, and last year in percentage.

How to get the value of c1, c2, c3, etc. in the previous week of this year and last year?

For example for c1, I tried the following code, but I get and error somehow. I used iloc[0] because the df is sorted descending. And tried to convert the "cw" from string to int so that I can substract 1 to get to the previous "cw" (from 45 to 44 for ex).

```
first_wow = (df[(df['c1'] == df.iloc[0]['c1']) & (
                int(df['cw']) == int(df.iloc[0]['cw']))].cnt.values[0] - df[
                        (df['c1'] == df.iloc[0]['c1']) & (
                                    int(df['cw']) == int(df.iloc[0]['cw']) - 1)].cnt.values[0]) / df[
                       (df['c1'] == df.iloc[0]['c1']) & (
                                   int(df['cw']) == int(df.iloc[0]['cw']) - 1)].cnt.values[0]
```

Comment: So basically how to get the value based on conditions above... How can I extract the value of c1 for previous week / year (in the same week)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which makes use of the pandas `groupby` method:

```
def prev_year(df):
    df = df.sort_values(['year'],ascending=[False])
    df['val_prev_yr'] = df['value'].shift(-1)
    df['prev_yr_diff'] = df['value'] - df['val_prev_yr']
    df['prev_yr_perc_diff'] = 100.0*df['prev_yr_diff']/df['val_prev_yr']
    return df

def prev_week(df):
    df = df.sort_values(['CW'],ascending=[False])
    df['val_prev_week'] = df['value'].shift(-1)
    df['prev_week_diff'] = df['value'] - df['val_prev_week']
    df['prev_week_perc_diff'] = 100.0*df['prev_week_diff']/df['val_prev_week']
    return df

def calcs(df):
    
    df2 = df.groupby('year').apply(prev_week).reset_index(drop=True)
    df2 = df.merge(df2[['val_prev_week','prev_week_diff','prev_week_perc_diff','year','CW']],how='left',on=['year','CW'])
    
    df3 = df2.groupby('CW').apply(prev_year).reset_index(drop=True)
    df4 = df2.merge(df3[['val_prev_yr','prev_yr_diff','prev_yr_perc_diff','year','CW']],how='left',on=['year','CW'])
    
    return df4
    
    
df.groupby('id').apply(calcs).sort_values(['year','CW'],ascending=[False,False]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image: output_df]

Comment: Let me know if this is what you were after and I can then add in comments to describe what's happening!

Comment: Yes, it is actually what I need!!! Thanks a lot!!! Really helpful! Just wanted to ask you, how could I manage it, if I had another grouping level (dimension) which is "country"? (I have 3 countries, country1, country2 and country3 and I want the values above for all 3 countries...

Comment: Glad this helps :) So to group the above by countries, you could write a new grouping function which returns the last line of the code above:  `def country_group_calcs(df):
 return df.groupby('id').apply(calcs)....`, and then simply call this function with `df.groupby('country').apply(country_group_calcs)` (assuming your column with countries is called "country").

Comment: and then if you wanted to tidy up the row index of the final output (which will be a MultiIndex) you can reset and drop the index using `.reset_index(drop=True)`